# How to get a Django admin form field for a models.DecimalField with value 0 not to use E notation

Tags: django, django-admin

We use django admin as a client-facing backend, so we need to make it user friendly.  I have a model with a bunch of DecimalFields representing nutritional data.

The fields all look like this:

```
g_carbs = DecimalField(max_digits=13, decimal_places = 8, null=True, blank=True)
```

If the field is left blank, or if a non-zero value is provided, the admin form looks and works great. For example, for a non-blank, non-zero value like 10.5, it displays something like `10.50000000`, which is fine.

The problem is that for any 0 values, the form field displays `0E-8`  which, although technically correct, is not going to cut it for my clients, who are definitely not scientists or engineers for the most part and are unfamiliar with E notation.

I am not using a custom form or any custom admin tricks.  Its just what gets auto-rendered by django admin for that model. I'm considering submitting a ticket to django for this, but in the mean time is there something I can do with a custom form or something to remedy this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what ended up working for me (so far).  This both prevents E notation and removes trailing 0's after the decimal point.

```
class NonscientificDecimalField(DecimalField):
    """ Prevents values from being displayed with E notation, with trailing 0's 
        after the decimal place  truncated. (This causes precision to be lost in 
        many cases, but is more user friendly and consistent for non-scientist 
        users)
    """
    def value_from_object(self, obj):
        def remove_exponent(val):
            """Remove exponent and trailing zeros.
               >>> remove_exponent(Decimal('5E+3'))
               Decimal('5000')
            """
            context = decimal.Context(prec=self.max_digits)
            return val.quantize(decimal.Decimal(1), context=context) if val == val.to_integral() else val.normalize(context)

        val = super(NonscientificDecimalField, self).value_from_object(obj)
        if isinstance(val, decimal.Decimal):
            return remove_exponent(val)
```

Answer (score 1):

One simple way might be to subclass DecimalField and change its formatting.

```
from django.db.models.fields import DecimalField

class NonscientificDecimalField(DecimalField):
    def format_number(self, value):
        """
        Overrides DecimalField's usual format_number by making sure 
        that the result is never in exponential notation for zero.
        """
        if value == 0:
            return "0.00000000"
        else:
            return super(DecimalField, self).format_number(value)
```

You shouldn't submit this as a Django bug, by the way - this is the way Python decimals work and has little to do with Django. Open up a shell and try `str(Decimal("0.00000000"))` and you'll see `Decimal('0E-8')`.

If you'd like to get `10.50000000` to show up as `10.5`, you can call `normalize` on your decimals. This will also fix your `0E-8` problem:

```
import decimal
from django.db.models.fields import DecimalField

class NonscientificDecimalField(DecimalField):
    def format_number(self, value):
        """
        Overrides DecimalField's usual format_number to remove trailing zeroes.
        """
        if isinstance(value, decimal.Decimal):
            context = decimal.Context(prec=self.max_digits)
            value = value.normalize(context=context)
        return super(DecimalField, self).format_number(value)
```

Comment: I set breakpoints, and format_number never gets called, so this wasn't a working solution. But you did set me on the right path, so thanks a bunch! At least in django 1.4, format_number appears to be deprecated. From the comments in the code: ## Method moved to django.db.backends.util. It is preserved because it is used by the oracle backend, and also for backwards-compatibility with any external code which may have used this method. ##  I posted what ended up working for me below for future Overflowers.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there has been a fix for it: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/19220 but I am not sure if it fully works because I am using django 1.6.5 and the admin displays `0E-8.00000000` or `0E-8` for `0`.

```
models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=8, null=True)
```

@Ben Roberts: Do you still have the issue?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for brining my attention to the fix! We are still on Django 1.5; and are using the workaround in the accepted answer. Once we update to 1.7 I'll check out the fix to see if it makes the workaround obsolete.

Comment: The fix is for the model field right? FYI, I just have an issue with zero.

Comment: Yes, its supposed to be for the model field although I haven't tested it yet. I may have only made it into 1.7, not sure.

Comment: Has this been fixed @BenRoberts? I still get numbers in scientific notation if number is as very small, like 0.00000067

Comment: IDK. Haven't had a chance to test it. Still using my patch and am still on Django 1.5. :)

Comment: i still got this E notation value when i use decimals=8 or larger in Decimal form for any 0 values (0, 0.0002,...)  on django version 2.2